# PHP 5.4 Interpreter for Eclipse PDT

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

So PHP 5.4 is released, but when will the interpreter come out for eclipse PDT to support the new syntax of PHP 5.4?

All I could find on the web so far is an old "Bug Report": https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362672. It seems like I can't even sign up there to post a question on its status.

Is somebody working on it? Is there dev version for it publicly available? How long does it typically take for them to release a new interpreter after a new PHP version comes out?

The PHP 5.4 syntax has been announced quite some time ago. How come its still not supported in Eclipse (I am not complaining, just want to know where it is hanging)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep there is an interpreter for PHP 5.4 although its seems buggy, static function click throughs dont work on my mac eclipse install and on my windows eclipse install no function click throughs work.

Give it a try

In your eclipse go to

Preferences -> PHP -> PHPInterpreter Then select PHP version to PHP 5.4

If it is not available then you will need to update your PDT

help -> Check for updates

I commented on the bug report you mentioned the other day before i realised there is an interpreter so you can sign up and comment your self go to...

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Seems to me the interpreter still needs some work though as would be nice to have better code assist with traits.

Comment: forgot to mention using eclipse indigo and PDT 3.0.0v2012

Comment: FYI for others that find this - on a fresh install of Eclipse 3.7.2, installing PDT via Install New Software will result in the 3.0.0v2011 version. Seems silly that you would need to do this, but you still gotta Check For Updates to get the new PDT...

Answer (score 0):

PDT versions >= 3.0.0 all support PHP 5.4, including trait support.

The current version, as of writing, is PDT 3.1.0, and 3.1.1 is available from the nightly [developer builds](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) update site:

- http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.1.1/nightly