# array_map showing syntax error in eclipse , but code is working fine

Tags: php, eclipse, array-map

I'm working with codeIgniter, and when I use PHP function `array_map`, it shows a syntax error, but the code is working fine. Is `array_map` a deprecated function?

Why is this happening?

[image]

Should I avoid using `array_map`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only define a function like that in PHP 5.3+.  Does your Eclipse know you're running PHP 5.3+?

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608747/php-5-4-interpreter-for-eclipse-pdt) to update your PHP interpreter.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: care to post this as an answer.  Or Kanishka, you can post your own answer.  Best to have an answer. The question shows as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Explosion Pills mentioned in his comment

> You can only define a function like that in PHP 5.3+.

so you should update your PHP interpreter in eclipse.
and to do that here's a post that will help you.
[PHP interpreter for eclipse.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608747/php-5-4-interpreter-for-eclipse-pdt)